# Count previous consecutive rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have attendance data list which is showing below. Now I am trying to find data by a specific date range (01/05/2016 – 07/05/2016) with total Present Column, Total Present Column will be calculated from previous present data (P). Suppose today is 04/05/2016. If a person has 01,02,03,04 status ‘p’ then it will show date 04-05-2016 total present 4.

[image]

Could you help me to find total present from this result set.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check this example, which have logic to calculate previous sum value.

```
declare @t table (employeeid int, datecol date, status varchar(2) )

insert into @t values (10001, '01-05-2016', 'P'),
(10001, '02-05-2016', 'P'),
(10001, '03-05-2016', 'P'),
(10001, '04-05-2016', 'P'),
(10001, '05-05-2016', 'A'),
(10001, '06-05-2016', 'P'),
(10001, '07-05-2016', 'P'),
(10001, '08-05-2016', 'L'),
(10002, '07-05-2016', 'P'),
(10002, '08-05-2016', 'L')

--select * from @t 

select * ,  
    SUM(case when status = 'P' then 1 else 0 end) OVER (PARTITION BY   employeeid ORDER BY employeeid, datecol
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
      AND current row) 
from 
@t
```

Another twist of the same thing via cte (as you written SQLSERVER2012, this below solution only work in Sqlserver 2012 and above)

```
;with cte as
(
    select  employeeid , datecol , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by employeeid order by employeeid, datecol) rowno
    from 
    @t where status = 'P'
)
select t.*, cte.rowno , 
    case when ( isnull(cte.rowno, 0) = 0) 
    then LAG(cte.rowno) OVER (ORDER BY t.employeeid, t.datecol) 
    else cte.rowno
    end LagValue 
from @t t left join cte on t.employeeid = cte.employeeid and t.datecol = cte.datecol
order by t.employeeid, t.datecol
```

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion.

Comment: I think the first solution only works in SQL 2012 too, no? If memory serves, that's when they added the windowing ability on aggregates.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a subquery to calculate `TotalPresent` for each row:

```
SELECT 
    main.EmployeeID, 
    main.[Date], 
    main.[Status], 
    (
        SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN t.[Status] = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
        FROM [TableName] t
        WHERE t.EmployeeID = main.EmployeeID AND t.[Date] <= main.[Date]
    ) as TotalPresent
FROM [TableName] main
ORDER BY 
    main.EmployeeID, 
    main.[Date]
```

Here I used subquery to count the sum of records that have the same `EmployeeID` and date is less or equal to the date of current row. If status of the record is 'P', then 1 is added to the sum, otherwise 0, which counts only records that have status P.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question, this should work:

```
select *
, (select count(retail) from p g 
   where g.date <= p.date and g.id = p.id and retail = 'P')
from p
order by ID, Date;
```

So I believe I understand correctly.  You would like to count the occurences of P per ID datewise.

This makes a lot of sense.  That is why the first occurrence of ID2 was L and the Total is 0.  This query will count P status for each occurrence, pause at non-P for each ID.

[Here is an example](http://rextester.com/IIVVYG84700)